# Why was Straighten Microphone Cables closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

Why was my question [Straighten microphone cables](https://superuser.com/questions/355253/straighten-microphone-cables) closed?

It is a practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that I currently face. It is **not** chatty or open-ended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually many reasons why this was closed as off topic.

- **It has nothing to do with computer hardware of software.**
- **Its not constructive.** - There isn't a real answer to this. You could possibly get a million different ways of organizing your cables out.
- **Its too localized** - This isn't going to help a lot of people in the long run.

Comment: I agree that it may not have anything to do with computer software, but I can say that [this](http://superuser.com/questions/32180/color-of-youtube-player) is just as poor a question.

Would it make that much of a difference if I would have said that I have a 3ft  Ethernet cable bent out of shape, and I need it to go 2.98ft, it doesn't reach because its bent...?

Comment: @wizlog a low-quality question from 3 years ago is not an excuse for a low-quality question today.

Comment: @wizlog That question is closed now. Very poor example too. the site has changed a lot over 2 years.

Comment: and I can't put a bounty on a closed question, right?

Comment: @wizlog No you can't... you wouldn't be able to get any answers.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Thank you for explaining this to me... I appreciate it.

Comment: @wizlog No problem

Answer (score 3):

The question is off-topic. You're asking about setting up audio recording equipment. As explained in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq/), questions should be about computer software and hardware, of which this is neither.

Comment: Its a computer accessory.  It plugs into my computer.

Comment: And shouldn't it then have been migrated?

Comment: If you think there is another site where your question would be appropriate, by all means, flag it for migration. But keep in mind that a) there are over 65 sites now; we can't remember them all, and b) we only migrate things when they're of a sufficient quality level. Your question isn't very easy to even understand what you're doing.

Comment: @wizlog Migrated to where?

Comment: @SimonSheehan I have no idea, I was just being hopeful...

Comment: there IS an AV SE site i believe.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek if you're talking about [avp.se], that's only for A/V _production_. It might be applicable, but I kind of doubt the question would be on topic there either.